# Where is the syntax error in this Javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

Here is the code:

```
    var disqus_title="UnicodeDecodeError - ordinal not in range(128)";
    var disqus_identifier="cache\yazilar\python\unicode-decode-error-ordinal-not-in-range.html";
    var disqus_config = function () {
        this.language = "tr";
    };
```

Chrome's debugging tool suggest that there is a syntax error in `disqus_identifier` line, but I can't find it. I use same code in all of my pages and only this one gives error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to double the backslashes in your string constant.

```
var disqus_identifier="cache\\yazilar\\python\\unicode-decode-error-ordinal-not-in-range.html";
```

It might be a good idea to make sure that you really want those backslashes and not forward-slash characters. If you're passing a path back to your server and your server's going to just use it blindly, that might be a fairly nasty security issue.

Answer (score 2):

The backslash `\` is an escape character in javascript. If you want a backslash in your string, you have to escape it with another backslash.

```
var disqus_identifier="cache\\yazilar\\python\\unicode-decode-error-ordinal-not-in-range.html";
```

Answer (score 1):

`\u` indicates a unicode escape. It must be followed by 4 hexidecimal characters.

You should probably either replace your `\` characters with `\\` (the escape sequence used to represent `\` as data) or (since what you have looks like a relative URI) use `/` instead.

Answer (score 0):

var disqus_identifier="cache\yazilar\python\unicode-decode-error-ordinal-not-in-range.html";

Single Backslash confuse Script Compiler.